# Why does my Kafka Streams topology does not replay/reprocess correctly?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topology that looks like this:

```
KTable<ByteString, User> users = topology.table(USERS);

KStream<ByteString, JoinRequest> joinRequests = topology.stream(JOIN_REQUESTS)
    .mapValues(entityTopologyProcessor::userNew)
    .to(USERS);

topology.stream(SETTINGS_CONFIRM_REQUESTS)
    .join(users, entityTopologyProcessor::userSettingsConfirm)
    .to(USERS);

topology.stream(SETTINGS_UPDATE_REQUESTS)
    .join(users, entityTopologyProcessor::userSettingsUpdate)
    .to(USERS);
```

At runtime this topology works fine. Users are created with join requests. They confirm their settings with settings confirm requests. They update their settings with settings update requests.

However, reprocessing this topology does not produce the original results. Specifically, the settings update joiner does not see the user that resulted from the settings confirm joiner, even though in terms of timestamps, many seconds elapse from the time the user is created, to the time the user is confirmed to the time the user updates their settings.

I'm at a loss. I've tried turning off caching/logging on the user table. No idea what to do to make this reprocess properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Over the years, a lot of effort was put into making Kafka Streams more deterministic.

Kafka Streams 2.1 added `max.task.idle.ms` config to help "synchronizing" reading from different input topic ([KIP-353](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-353%3A+Improve+Kafka+Streams+Timestamp+Synchronization)) which was further improved in 3.0 release ([KIP-695](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-695%3A+Further+Improve+Kafka+Streams+Timestamp+Synchronization))

For stream-table join in particular, versioned state stores (added in 3.5: [KIP-889](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-889%3A+Versioned+State+Stores)) can now we leveraged with a stream-table join "grace period" (added in 3.6: [KIP-923](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-923%3A+Add+A+Grace+Period+to+Stream+Table+Join)) to provide deterministic and temporally accurate join results.

**Original Answer**

A KStream-KTable join is not 100% deterministic (and might never become 100% deterministic). We are aware of the problem and discuss solutions, to at least mitigate the issue.

One problem is, that if a Consumer fetches from the brokers, we cannot control easily for which topics and/or partitions the broker returns data. And depending on the order in which we receive data from the broker, the result might slightly differ.

One related issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3514

This blog post might help, too: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

Comment: Right, but is there a way I could obviate this problem? I've observed that in some circumstances I do get the correct computation. But I have not been able to determine what causes the results to be correct.For example, would it make sense for me to try launching the topology with fewer threads during the reprocess? Would it make sense for launch the topology with fewer input tasks? Things like that. I have been expecting "slight" differences, but I am seeing rather substantial differences. I've read that blog post several times.

Comment: Would making the buffer bigger help, etc? I have no out of order timestamps like in that JIRA. I will investigate the empty buffer issue from the JIRA. It's shame on me for not playing more with this and identifying this problem earlier, but the idea that my steam applications actually not at all replayable—aka the whole promise of stream processing—is incredibly disappointing. I have got to believe there is some way to mitigate this.

Comment: For unit-testing/integration-testing, you need to make sure hat the records are passed in the right order. If you go with a system test setup, the order is very hard to enforce. Making sure, that a single thread processed fewer tasks and increasing the consumer request size might help to improve the behavior. The blog post does not really cover those details to be fair... :(

Comment: I cross-posted this to the list-serv, sorry. There I replied that I will try replacing all problematic KStream-KTable joins with KStream#transform(). I am hopeful about this. Should I be? Not sure what you mean by unit/integration testing, but I see how it could be relevant given that I am processing an existing history. But hey I saw that new testing KIP today—looks exciting! Been using the private version and it’s already pretty good.

Comment: ... and just saw your reply there. Thanks, I will try KStream#transform()

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky: You mentioned elsewhere that Flink might be a better option than Kafka Streams in this scenario.  It is not -- Flink, too, uses Kafka's consumer client to read from Kafka and thus suffers from the same problem that Matthias J. Sax described above.

Comment: Does Flink offer a left/outer stream-stream join or stream-table join in the first place? Would be new to me.

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll I updated my answer elsewhere to remove that part. Matthias clarified some things about Flink for me over email after I did that update. Anyway, it was beyond the scope of that question email. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax hehe no they do not :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to partially solve my problem by replacing the code in the question with:

```
KTable<ByteString, User> users = topology.table(JOIN_REQUESTS)
    .mapValue(entityTopologyProcessor::user)
    .leftJoin(topology
                 .stream(CONFIRM_SETTINGS_REQUESTS)
                 .groupByKey()
                 .reduce((a, b) -> b),
              entityTopologyProcessor::confirmSettings)
    .leftJoin(topology
                 .stream(SETTINGS_UPDATE_REQUESTS)
                 .groupByKey()
                 .reduce(entityTopologyProcessor::settingsUpdateReduce),
              entityTopologyProcessor::settingsUpdate);
```

This solution leverages the fact that all table-table joins are deterministic. During reprocess, resulting state may temporarily be incorrect, but once the topology is caught up, the final value is correct (the final timestamp for a given result will still not be deterministic). Generally speaking, this approach, this groups all the events (in this example: join requests, confirm settings requests, settings update requests) for a given entity (in this example: user) into a single task and joins their accumulations into a single product. This example could be extended with delete events by joining another stream at the end that nulls the result.

Beyond this approach, generally, writing a reprocessable topology requires thinking about the topology in two dimensions: real-time and reprocess-time. As of Kafka Streams 1.0.0, this is something of an art for the developer.