# How to make multiple logs sync in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Suppose I have 2 types of logs, which have a common field 'uid', and I want to output the log if the log of both of these 2 logs containing the uid arrives, like a join, is it possible for Kafka ?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a note about determinism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Check out Kafka Streams, specifically the DSL API. It goes something like:

```
 StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

 KStream<byte[], Foo> fooStream = builder.stream("foo");

 KStream<byte[], Bar> barStream = builder.stream("bar");

 fooStream.join(barStream,
                (foo, bar) -> {
                    foo.baz = bar.baz;
                    return foo;
                },
                JoinWindows.of(1000))
          .to("buzz");
```

This simple application consumes two input topics ("foo" and "bar"), joins them and writes them to topic "buzz". Since streams are infinite, when joining two streams you need to specify a join window (1000 milliseconds above), which is the relative time difference between two messages on the respective streams to make them eligible for joining.

Here is a more complete example: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/PageViewRegionLambdaExample.java

And here is the documentation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html. You'll find there are many different kinds of joins you can perform:

- https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html
- https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html

It is important to note that although the above example will deterministically synchronize streams—if you reset and reprocess the topology, you will get the same result each time—not all join operations in Kafka Streams are deterministic. As of version 1.0.0 and before, approximately half are not deterministic and may depend on the order of data consumed from the underlying topic-partitions. Specifically, inner `KStream`-`KStream` and all `KTable`-`KTable` joins are deterministic. Other joins, like all `KStream`-`KTable` joins and left/outer `KStream`-`KStream` joins are non-deterministic and depend on order of data consumed by consumers. Keep this in mind if you are designing your topology to be reprocessable. If you use these non-deterministic operations, when your topology is running live, the order of events as they arrive will produce one result, but if you are reprocessing your topology you may get another result. Note also operations like `KStream#merge()` do not produce deterministic results either. For more regarding this problem, see [Why does my Kafka Streams topology does not replay/reprocess correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287840/why-does-my-kafka-streams-topology-does-not-replay-reprocess-correctly) and this [mailing list post](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/c9397e6a0b34c03052d83680956c7045b5ceef7359e78ef8e457bd85@%3Cusers.kafka.apache.org%3E)